# Prove that if $a b c=1$, $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge 3$. (for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I can do this problem using calculus minimization techniques, using Lagrange multipliers to find the equations $a^2=b^2=c^2$, so with $abc=1$, $a$, $b$, and $c$, are either $-1$ or $1$ (making sure you don't end up with $abc$ negative). So if the minimum distances are at those points, then $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$ is the closest distance, so all other solutions are further away.

I just pieced together (while writing this) that there's another solution: The arithmetic-geometric inequality gives $3(abc)^{1/3}\le a+b+c$, and by [the inequality of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65695/proving-that-for-reals-a-b-c-a-b-c2-leq-3a2b2c2), we have $9(abc)^{2/3}\le (a+b+c)^2\le 3(a^2+b^2+c^2)$, so since $abc=1$, we have $3\le a^2+b^2+c^2$.

But, is it possible to prove this using other inequality tricks? It's just, the inequality on the link I gave, I had no idea about, so it's uncomfortable to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By AM/GM, we have 
$$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}\ge (a^2b^2c^2)^{1/3}=1.$$

Comment: OH! Duh. So I can just take the AM/GMs of $a^2,b^2$ etc. instead of $a,b,\ldots$. Makes sense!

Comment: Yes, it is pleasantly simple.